# Raven Index Efficiency: Map Reduce vs. Transformer

Tags: ravendb

I'm wondering what is most efficient in Raven, using a transformer or using a map reduce.  I'm looking at a case where all fields from several collections are returned, but I only need a fraction of them indexed.  I ran a test on one example and I found that both Index building and Index retrieval is faster using the transformer.  I'd like to know if this result will hold and what Raven is doing in the background to increase efficiency.

Below is a "toy example", where a Professor can teach in multiple Classes.  I only need an index on Classes.Name.

```
    Collection: Professors
       ProfessorID, Name, PField1, PField2, ...
    Collection: Classes
       ClassID, Name, ProfessorID, CField1, CField2, ...
```

**Transformer pseudo-code:**

```
    Map:
       from class in docs.Classes select new {Name = class.Name}
    Transformer:
       from result in results
       let prof = LoadDocument(result.ProfessorID)
       select new { 
          result.ClassID, result.Name, result.ProfessorID, 
          result.CField1, result.CField2, ...
          prof.Name, prof.PField1, prof.PField2, ...
       }
```

**Map/Reduce pseudo-code**

```
    Map1:
       from prof in Professors
       select { all fields}
    Map2: 
       from class in Classes
       select {all fields}
    Reduce
       from result in results
       group result by result.ProfessorID into g
       select {all fields}
```

Answer (score 0):

A transformer runs during query, so it only does the work when/if you need it to.
Map/Reduce is meant to *reduce the data*, for aggregation, not really for what you are using it for.
It runs in the background and will build the projection for you.

I would recommend transformer for this.